# Polynomial Interpolation and Error bound 2

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let function $f$ is $C^2[-1,1]$. Interpolate the function by a linear polynomial through the support point {$(x_0,f(x_0),(x_1,f(x_1)$} for $x_0,x_1\in [-1,1]$.

I proved Error term is bounded by $\alpha$
\begin{equation}
\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\text{max}_{\xi \in [-1,1]}\vert f^{''}(\xi)\vert \text{max}_{x\in [-1,1]} \vert (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\vert
\end{equation}

I have problems

(1)  Which Value $x_0,x_1$ minimize $\alpha$?

I think $\text{max}_{x\in [-1,1]} \vert (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\vert=\vert\frac{(x_1-x_0)^2}{2}\vert$ since $x=\frac{x_0+x_1}{2}$ satisfies maximum of $\vert (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\vert$.
However, $x_0\neq x_1$.... Thus, I cannot find $x_0,x_1$ values for minimizing $\alpha$.

(2) What is the connection between $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ and $cos(2arccos(x))??

I don't know (2) problem's purpose and intention..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also to take the interval end points into consideration. Then indeed you can minimize the maximum of the values at these 3 points $-1,\frac{x_0+x_1}2,1$,
$$
\max\Bigl((1-x_0)(1-x_1), \frac14(x_1-x_0)^2, (1+x_0)(1+x_1)\Bigr)
$$
In a symmetric configuration $x_0=-x_1$, this reduces to the maximum of $1-x_1^2$ and $x_1^2$, which is minimal for $x_1=\sqrt{\frac12}$.

Comment: I missed boundary points... Thank you